# How to add a 10 minute reminder through shortcut?

Tags: iphone, ios, shortcut, automation, reminders

I'm on iOS 15 and what I'm looking for is a way to add a 10 minute reminder to 'wake up'.

I can do the same by asking Siri to 'remind me to wake up in 10 minutes', but I'd like a way to create a shortcut for this so that I can do this quietly.

I tried creating a shortcut for adding a reminder, but then shortcuts can only be added for a specific time (like 10AM  tomorrow), but not with a specific time limit like 10 minutes from now.

Specifically, the end result should add a reminder for 10 minutes from now, and it should be done with a shortcut icon on the home screen. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I've tried creating the short to add a reminder, but reminder can only be added with a specific time, and not with a duration, like 10 minutes from now. I've tried creating a shortcut to mimic a Siri command but it again prompts me to specify time for the reminder. I've tried creating a shortcut to repeat last siri command but that also didn't work. Please help. Added this to original question.

Answer (score 1):

I made a [shortcut which does exactly this](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/256d4dfc54d546c3b74dde3c74e46b84).

[image: Screenshot of the shortcut1]